# Django Queryset Filter where will be 3 month in 7 days

Tags: python, django

I have queryset filtered user that created 3 month ago.

```
User.objects.filter(
    create_date__range=(
        datetime.now()-timedelta(90),datetime.now()
    )
)
```

that above return all the user within date range 3 month ago to now. but i don't need return it all since its to many.

I need return all the user that will be 3 month in 7 days from `datetime.now()`.

example.
now = `2018-05-29`

create_date = `2018-04-20` will now show since its more than 7 days till 3 month.
create_date = `2018-03-04` <-- this will show since in 6 days will be 3 month.

Comment: acticle? Do you mean user?

Comment: ah sorry, yes its user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `create_date` is a `models.DateField()`.

If I understand your question correctly, you could try something this:

```
import datetime as dt
from django.utils import timezone as tz

today_ = tz.now().date()
today_plus_7 = today_ + dt.timedelta(days=7)
today_plus_7_minus_90 = today_plus_7 - dt.timedelta(days=90)

# users that are 83 days or YOUNGER
#qs = User.objects.filter(create_date__range=[
#    today_plus_7_minus_90, today_plus_7])
qs = User.objects.filter(create_date__gte=today_plus_7_minus_90)

# users that are 83 days or OLDER
qs = User.objects.filter(create_date__lte=today_plus_7_minus_90)
```